# Django: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt -> mail backends not correctly set?

Tags: python, django, email

I currently develop a Django project and want to send email for 2 purposes:

- password reset
- database update

I have a registration app I developp following https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com tutorials and it works well. For tutorial purpose, reset send email in console. I would like to test real email sent using my google account (even if it will probably not be the service I will use but I want to understand concepts)

I have read the Django doc about email sending

I have the Django default authentification and a function email() for database update called in code when one of my models is updated

At home it works but in my entreprise, I got the following error:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

it is a firewall problem I guess... I should I resole it?

**models.py**

```
def email(patient,strategie,medicament): 

    subject = 'Patient ' + patient + ' randomisé '
    message = 'Le patient ' + patient + ' a été randomisé dans la stratégie ' + strategie + ' et a reçu le numéro de boite ' + medicament
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [
        'j.lecarrou@gmail.com',

        ]

    email = send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)

    return email
```

**settings.py**

````
#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '************'```
````

Comment: Try sending the email through Python shell. If that doesn't go through, it's most probably caused by your company's firewall.

Comment: ok, it failed for the same reasons...

Comment: it was the firewall as it work at home..